# How to delay some cron jobs?

Tags: magento2, admin, cron, performance

I'm having many performance issues because of my cron jobs, I suspect that it may be caused by two modules, Yotpo and Scconnector, both have options in the `system > configuration`.

I'd like to know how could I configure it via these options below to get them having a delay?

[image: Magento2 admin panel cron configuration]

Answer (score 0):

You can set different time for your cron group for execution. Like one group you can execute on every one hour and second group you can execute on every 2-3 hours.

For that you need to modify your module **crontab.xml** file

Change schedule tag code for every one hour:

```
<schedule>* */1 * * *</schedule>
```

For two hours:

```
<schedule>* */2 * * *</schedule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored any extensions? Wyomind cron scheduler gives you more control over Magento cron tasks.

Get the latest version from the website and not git. The version on the website is newer and has bug fixes.