# Magento 2 What is the Cron Group / Module "Scconnector"?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.3.3

I've noticed the cron group "Scconnector" found in the admin area under; system > configuration > Cron. What is this Module?

The reason why I ask is I have noticing some CPU spikes when running the command 'top'. There are 5 cron processes running at the same time every minute.

Two of these are Yotpo and Scconnector modules. Since I don't use Yotpo I disabled the module. I am curious as to what this modules does so I can decide if I need it enabled. I can't seem to find much about this "Scconnector"

My issue is similar to what I've found here (see link below), but my question is different to what is being asked: [How to delay some cron jobs?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294681/how-to-delay-some-cron-jobs).

Comment: It is a huge puzzle to me that if you do not use modules, like Amazon payments or Yotpo or google shopping ads - all not enabled in config - the system STILL generates these cron commands

Comment: Not everyone sells in America. Here in Australia Amazon has little to no market share in our retail space. We already use a feed generator for other b2b platforms, which is just fine for Google Shopping needs. The system does not generate these commands if they are disabled and removed via composer cli. Puzzle solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is for Google Shopping ads.
You can go to terminal and run php bin/magento cron:show. Look at the class column and confirm your cron jobs.

Comment: Thank you confirming the module name. I'll consider if I need this module since I already exporting a csv feed to google. 

On another note, the cron:show command listed responds with the error ' is not defined'

Comment: I'd mark this as answered if the cron:show command was correct.